# Given a array with a blank element how do I print all elements except the blank one?

Tags: java, arrays, element, chars

I have a array of **chars** called votacoes. And when I do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nDeputados; i++) {
    System.out.println(votacoes[i]);
}
```

the output is:

```
S
A

S
S
S
N
A
```

As you can see you there is a blank char in index 2.

To print everything except the blank char what is the condition in the following if?

```
for (int i = 0; i < nDeputados; i++) {
    if(???????????){
        System.out.println(votacoes[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `votacoes`? What does `votacoes[i]` return? What does "empty element" means? (empty String, blank String...)

Comment: Fixed my answer, will work for char[]. You should have given those details earlier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nDeputados; i++)
{
 if(Character.isAlphabetic(votacoes[i]))

      System.out.println(votacoes[i]);
}
```

The Character.isAlphabetic() method returns true if the value passed is an alphabet. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Who said OP didn't want to print `-`? Only "empty elements" are mentioned.

Comment: @Tunaki you are right. now why didn't i think about that

Comment: Thanks so much. This works like a charm and my algorithm is now fully working thanks to you!

Comment: @Tunaki , in this case it works because my array can only have Alphabetic characters

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks, from now on i will try to understand  question much more clearly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nDeputados; i++) {
    if(!String.valueOf(votacoes[i]).matches("\\s")){
        System.out.println(votacoes[i]);
    }
}
```

This will skip up any type of `space` characters and print out a continuous output.

Comment: If you are downvoting you should also provide a reason for that.

Comment: Now that you have edited your answer to use char[] instead of only strings, this line doesn't make sense: `if(!String.valueOf(votacoes[i]).equals(""))` Since votacoes[i] is a char, it will always have length of 1 and so will never be "". By the way, you should call String.isEmpty() rather than equals("").

Comment: Yup, you are right. Code "Trimmed". And I use `""` because you dont have to check for `null` in that. So it does work fine for me in a lot of situations...  but yeah, `.equals()` is cleaner and actually does a good `null` check too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String isBlank method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nDeputados; i++) {
    if(!StringUtils.isBlank(votacoes[i])){
    System.out.println(votacoes[i]);
    }
}
```

Look here:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```
      for (int k = 0; k < votacoes.length; k++) {
        if (votacoes[k]==' ') {
            k++;
        }
        System.out.println(votacoes[k]);
```

hope it would work for you..

Comment: Which gives a nice `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if the last character is a space.

Comment: @Tunaki  Ohh that's right, it was just slipped from my mind, thanks 
                                                                                `Character.isAlphabetic(array[k])` would be perfect here as I know

Answer (score -1):

```
char[] votacoes = {'S','A',' ','S','S','S','N','A'};
for (char b : votacoes) {
    if(!Character.isWhitespace(b)) {
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```